# Euclidean cirle question

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $c_1$ be a circle with center $O$. Let angle $ABC$ be an inscribed angle of the circle $c_1$.

i) If $O$ and $B$ are on the same side of the line $AC$, what is the relationship between $\angle ABC$ and $ \angle AOC$?

ii) If $O$ and $B$ are on opposite side of the line $AC$, what is the relationship between $\angle ABC$ and $\angle AOC$

I guess $\angle ABC=(1/2) \angle AOC$ but I don't know how to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here $O$ and $B$ are on the same side of of the line $AC$, you can figure out the other part.

$\angle AOB=180-2y$ and $\angle COB=180-2x$

$\angle AOB+ \angle COB=360-2(x+y) \implies \angle AOC=2(x+y) \implies 2 \angle ABC$.

This is known widely as [Inscribed Angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) as RobJohn said in his comment.:)

Comment: The classical proof (+1). This is called [The Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

Comment: Yes, it is. I have included that now. :)